# Scala Script: How to provide inputs to StdIn before it asks?

Tags: scala

This is what my script looks like

```
$cat automate.scala
import scala.io.StdIn

println("What's your name:")
val name = StdIn.readLine()
println(s"Hello $name")
```

When I run, I do

```
$ scala automate.scala
What's your name:
James bond
Hello James bond
```

However, I wanted to pass the options on command-line as

```
$ scala automate.scala JamesBond
```

But when I do, I still get

```
$ scala automate.scala JamesBond
What's your name:
James Bond
Hello James Bond
```

How can I handle this given that `StdIn` part will remain there as is

Comment: `echo JamesBond | scala automate.scala`?

Answer (score 0):

That's like asking how to answer the telephone before someone calls you; StdIn gets input on-demand from the terminal, nothing else.

Command-line arguments passed to a Scala program/script are made available in an `Array[String]` named `args`. So you could do this instead:

```
$cat automate.scala

import scala.io.StdIn

println("What's your name?")

val name = {
  if (args.nonEmpty) 
    args(0)
  else 
    StdIn.readLine()
}

println(s"Hello $name")
```